# Mustache js - Get json array name

Tags: mustache

```
[{
    "ASIN": "B009NPAORC",
    "itemTitle": "Goliton with Andriod"
}]
```

In the above code i want to get `ASIN` value in `mustache` template like `{{}}`. what will be in `{{}}`?

Answer (score 1):

Giving your value to a variable:

```
var objs = [ { "ASIN": "B009NPAORC", "itemTitle": "Goliton with Andriod" } ];
```

We can either pull the individual array element out in the template using:

```
<li>{{objs.0.ASIN}}: {{objs.0.itemTitle}}</li>
```

Or loop the array with:

```
{{#each objs}}
    <li>{{this.ASIN}}: {{this.itemTitle}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: i am using API and can't use var objs.and i want to get just "ASIN".and don't want to get ASIN value.